# Estimating the natural logarithm from both sides: $1/(a+1)<\ln((1+a)/a) <1/a$

Tags: inequality, logarithms

I must prove that for all $a>0$ 
 $$\frac{1}{a+1}<\ln{\frac{1+a}{a}}<\frac{1}{a}$$
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Hint: $\ln((1+a)/a)=\int_1^{1+1/a} 1/x\,dx$. Approximate this integral with the area of rectangles.

Comment: yea, but i dont know integrals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $f(x)=\log (a+x)$, $x \in [0,1]$. Then
$$
\log \frac{1+a}{a} = \log (1+a)-\log a = f(1)-f(0).
$$
But
$$
f'(x)=\frac{1}{a+x},
$$
and by the mean value theorem there is $c \in (0,1)$ such that $f(1)-f(0)=f'(c)$. Now,
$$
\frac{1}{a+1} < \frac{1}{a+c} < \frac{1}{a},
$$
and you conclude.

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
\log\left(\frac{a+1}{a}\right)=\int_a^{a+1}\frac1x\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
Since $\frac1{a+1}\lt\frac1x\lt\frac1a$ on $(a,a+1)$ (which has unit length), we have that
$$
\frac1{a+1}\lt\log\left(\frac{a+1}{a}\right)\lt\frac1a
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\ln \frac{a+1}{a} = \ln (a+1) - \ln ( a) = \ln ( 1 + \frac{1}{a}) > 0$$
$$\ln \frac{1}{a + 1} = \ln (1) - \ln (a + 1) < 0$$
$$\ln \frac{1}{a} = \ln{1} - \ln { a } > \ln 1 - \ln(a+1)$$
$$\ln x >\ \ln y \rightarrow x > y $$

Using the last statement that log is monotonically increasing, and the previous three, you should be able to deduce your inequality.